# How do I start a game from Steam from a batch file and wait for it to exit?

Tags: steam

I have an autohost app for Space Empires which I use to process turns in multiplayer games, but when I hook it up to the Steam instance of SE5, I find that it uploads the turn before it finishes processing!

Here is the command line I'm using in my batch file:

`"C:\Users\edkol\Documents\Apps\Steam\steam.exe" -applaunch 1690 %*`

And the arguments that get passed in as `%*` are just the standard SE5 command line arguments to process a turn, something like this template:

`"{EnginePath}\Savegame\{GameCode}.gam" "{Password}" -moddir "{ModPath}"`

So is there something I can add to my command line to wait for SE5 to exit before returning?

Comment: You might try the solution on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814464/make-batch-start-wait-command-wait-for-programs-launch)

Answer (score 0):

So, when you launch the game with the Steam executable in your example, adding `/wait` to the command will launch the game and wait until *Steam* quits (even if you quit the game long before)

You will need to find the game executable and launch it directly *(if the game was installed with Steam, launching the game directly should also launch the Steam client, and that is OK)*:

```
start /wait "" /D"<STEAM ROOT>\SteamApps\common\<GAME DIR>" "<GAME LAUNCHER>.exe"
```

Now, this will **not** work for every game. Some launchers are merely a stub that will launch *another* executable that is the *real* game. This varies by game, and you might need to dig around to figure out what the parameters are to launch the real game directly.

Source: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

---

*My only real success with running an application that had a stub launcher has been with Arduino 1.8.11. And there, I simply got lucky: it is a Java application and all the launch parameters were visible in the stub launcher binary as plain text*

[image]